# Keep count of same-level elements in recursive ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

I'm trying to keep track of the sum of a particular `n` property of a nested tree-like array, but I'm not getting very good results.

#### [Plunkr Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GqpqZr?p=preview)

***JavaScript***

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive('layout', function() {

  return {
    templateUrl: 'layout',
    controller: function($scope) {

      // Running total function
      $scope.count = function(n) {
        if (!$scope.total) $scope.total = 0;
        $scope.total += parseInt(n, 10);
        return $scope.total;
      }

      // Tree-like array
      $scope.data = {
        'nodes': [{
          'name': 'layout',
          'n': 1,
          'nodes': [
            {'name': 'box','n': 1}, 
            {'name': 'box','n': 1}, 
            {'name': 'box','n': 1}, 
            {'name': 'box','n': 1}
          ]
        }, {
          'name': 'layout',
          'n': 1,
          'nodes': [
            {'name': 'box','n': 1}, 
            {'name': 'box','n': 1}, 
            {'name': 'box','n': 1}, 
            {'name': 'box','n': 1}
          ]
        }]
      };

    }
  }
});
```

***HTML***

```
<!-- Directive -->
<div layout></div>

<!-- Templates -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="layout">
<div class="layout" ng-repeat-start="data in data.nodes" ng-include="data.name"></div>
<div ng-repeat-end style="text-align:center;"><i>running total: {{ count(data.n) }}</i></div>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="box">
<div class="box">.</box>
</script>
```

1. Somehow, the count seems to start at 93. - *I've been pointed out by @Josep that this is because $digest is making that function recurse.*
2. The order is wrong.
3. Count isn't being reset at each new recursion level.

#### Problem:

[image: Problem]

#### Expected outcome:

[image: Expected]

I've experimented with the following methods, with no luck:

1. Counter as a service ([Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DLNQMP?p=preview)). *At least the numbers went down*
2. No `ng-repeat-start`, `ng-repeat-end` ([Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/F1nWaE?p=preview)). We miss the nested counts.

And besides those things, I've been mostly tinkering to see if *I get lucky*. Honestly I don't really have a clue how this is supposed to work.

Please, any help figuring this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `count` function, just do this:

```
<div class="layout" ng-repeat-start="data in data.nodes" ng-include="data.name"></div>
<div ng-repeat-end style="text-align:center;"><i>running total: {{ ($index+1) }}</i></div>
```

### [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/uBfwgrfnAW73BicM5vtl?p=preview)

### Update

You can not use a function like that inside an `ng-repeat` expression, because that function will get evaluated in each `$digest` cycle and it will retrieve a different value every time, which will force the $digest to re-evaluate the result, which will retrieve a different value, and so on so forth until it has tried 10 times...

If you need to do this kind of aggregates for the data of your `ng-repeat`, I think that what you should do is create a custom filter that should be used inside the `ng-repeat` (or the `ng-repeat-start`), that `filter` would retrieve a copy of your array of objects but adding the aggregate information as a new key of each item, so that you can consume it as any other property of the items of your iterations.

Something like this: `ng-repeat-start="data in data.nodes|aggregate:'fieldToAggregate'"`

### Udate 2

On a second thought, there is a way to make your `count function` work, it's quite hacky but it works, change your `count function`, make it look like this:

```
  $scope.count = function(scope_, n) {
    if (!scope_.hasOwnProperty("__total")){
      if(!scope_.$parent.hasOwnProperty("__count")){
        scope_.$parent.__count=0;
      }
      scope_.$parent.__count+=parseInt(n, 10);
      scope_.__total=scope_.$parent.__count;
    }
    return scope_.__total;
  }
```

And use it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat-end style="text-align:center;"><i>running total: {{ count(this, data.n) }}</i></div>
```

### [Working Examle](http://plnkr.co/edit/sjfQB0WV9u8x06JhsmAa?p=preview)

This function shouldn't fail like the other one because this one will always return the same result every time that it's evaluated in the scope of your repeated items.

Comment: Looks like you missed the part where it has to sum the 'n' property, not the index. 'n' is 1 in this example, but it could be any number! (and not always the same in each node)

Comment: @AlainJacometForte your function will get evaluated in each $digest cycle and it will retrieve a different value every time, which will force the $digest to re-evaluate the result, which will retrieve a different value, and so on so forth until it hits that function 10 times...

Comment: I know my implementation is wrong, that's why I'm asking this question... If the question is unclear let me know and I'll make some edits.

Comment: @AlainJacometForte ok, ok, I'm updating my answer, I will explain you how I think that you should do that, my apologies if I've been too rough.

Comment: No prob 'the heat of the moment', any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: I added your explanation of the $digest recursion issue to the question, I'll try it out and I'll be updating info soon, thanks!

Comment: @AlainJacometForte I have updated my answer, please have a look at it, thanks!

Comment: Nice, you cracked it. I was going to try a Filter right now. Much better. Accepting as answer, thanks!

Comment: @AlainJacometForte Thanks! if I have time this weekend I will create a filter for this, so you don't have to do something so "hacky".

Answer (score 2):

The recursive ng-include *really* messed with my head, but this seems to do what you want.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zSua9RzVQOpbZmLJsSKF?p=preview)

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="layout">
<div class="layout" ng-repeat-start="data in data.nodes" ng-include="data.name" ng-init="data.t = ($parent.data.nodes[$index -1].t || 0) + data.n"></div>
<div ng-repeat-end style="text-align:center;"><i>running total: {{ data.t }}</i></div>
</script>
```

Each ng-init we set this data's t property equal to (previous.t + this.n). We access the previous by going up one level ($parent) and then using nodes[$index-1]

Comment: Wow hey, I didn't pay attention to this answer, but it's excellent. It works. I made a plunkr of it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/PgyGeJDCRCFeMeFw2HY1?p=preview. Sorry I already accepted an answer, but would you care to ellaborate? The first level sum still doesn't add up.

Comment: I reread the question and realised I *still* didn't get the recursive ng-include. The previous answer didn't work for more than one level of recursion. Once I got that the data object on each level of the ng-repeat was isolated, it made a lot more sense. Answer is a lot cleaner now, however it does add a new property to the data.